# Bidirectional tag stack movement with cscope in vim

Tags: tags, count, cscope

When using ctags, one can move back through the tag stack by using [count]<kbd>CTRL-T</kbd> or `:[count]pop`, and forward using `:[count]tag`

However, when using cscope instead of ctags and setting `'cscopetag'`, only the backwards direction works (that is, `:[count]pop` works, but `:[count]tag` gives `E433: No tags file` and `E426: tag not found` with the name of the tag at that point in the tagstack).

Is there a way to enable the forward direction when using cscope?

Comment: I haven't used cscope (didn't even know it existed!), but the documentation makes it sound like this is supposed to just work. Have you got `csto` set to zero? (the default)

Comment: I do: `set csto?` shows `cscopetagorder=0`

Answer (score 3):

Ensure setting the cscope using the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set cscopetag
set cst
set csto=0
set tags=./tags,tags;/
cs add cscope.out
```

Once it is done, re-login into the terminal to run cscope.

Jump to a tag: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

Jump back: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

Jump to a tag again: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to Vi stack exchange! ctrl+o and ctrl+i walk the jump list. This works great so long as one doesn't jump around between tag switches, which is often the case when just walking through a couple function calls, so have an upvote. Unfortunately for me, I sometimes move around a lot at a given call level which breaks this, or bounce between different tags which can get the jump list out-of-sync with my tag stack.

Answer (score 0):

Other than generate the `cscope.out`, you need to run `ctags -L cscope.files` to generate the `tags` file. With both of that you can move back and force in the cscope tagstack